# Android array adapters

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, string, csv

I am a newbie to android application development. I am currently working on a project which deals with the import of csv files which consists of only one column and many rows , onto my android project. I am able to read those csv files onto my project using csv adapters and array adapters and I didn't use any string arrays. Only used csvadapter and array adapters. Now in the list view where all the csv datas are presented, I am having a concern where when clicked on an item in the list I wanted to toast the item name. I tried out all possible combinations but it displays me only a toast saying string@somerandomvalue. Request someone to help me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
The following is my csvadapter class. The .csv files are in placed in assets folder.. 

public class CSVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<clock>{
    Context ctx;
    public CSVAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId)
    {
        super (context,textViewResourceId);
        this.ctx = context;
        loadArrayFromFile();
    }
    @Override
public View getView(final int pos,View convertView,final ViewGroup parent){
    TextView mView=(TextView)convertView;
    if(null == mView){
        mView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        mView.setTextSize(28);
    }
    mView.setText(getItem(pos).getTime());
    return mView;
}
```

**And this is my class to read that .csv array into GUI**

```
public class mrvtoparanur extends Activity {
CSVAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mrvtoparanur);
      final ListView mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mrvtoparanurlist);
      mAdapter=new CSVAdapter(this,-1);
      mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);   
      mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
      {
          @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you selected item number"+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }});
}
```

Comment: Post your code attempt.

Comment: have you use "ListView" "setOnItemClickListener()" ???

Comment: post your code so that we can understand what you are displaying?, and whats goin wrong.?

Comment: you said one column and many rows, if rows are having different items then you have to use custom adapter and if they contain single text then simple array adapter is enough..as some one above said overide that setOnItemclickListener and you can get item with position ..

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.. And for the code. Do you need the array adapter code ?

Comment: Please as requested i have pasted the code. Request someone to help on this. Also now when i have arg2 in the toast (in the 2nd java class code attached) it shows me the item id(no.) but i wanted to show the item name itself as the toast message. Pls help someone!